# What's the simplest way to add '0' for month and day which are integers?

Tags: python, if-statement, f-string

I have inputs `month` and `day` which are both `int` type, I want to pass them to a function to construct a path, and if `month` or `day` are numbers below 10, we add a `0` in front of the number:

```
def construct_path(year, month, day):
    if month >= 10 or day >= 10:
       path = f"xxx/{year}/{month}/{day}"
    elif month < 10 and day >= 10:
       path = f"xxx/{year}/0{month}/{day}"
    elif month >=10 and day <10:
       path = f"xxx/{year}/{month}/0{day}"
    else:
       path = f"xxx/{year}/0{month}/0{day}"
    return path
```

So `construct_path(2021, 5, 2)` should return `xxx/2021/05/02`.

The code works but looks complicated, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: use `zfill` for this purpose or use `datetime`

Comment: So it returned ```xxx/2021/05/02```

Comment: Perhaps using datetime is more convenient https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:02d` with formatting to allocate two spaces for a digit, and fill it up with 0 if the space remains empty.

```
def construct_path(year, month, day):
    return f'xxx/{year}/{month:02d}/{day:02d}'
```

Comment: A quick follow-up question, what is the inputs `year`, `month` and `day` are strings and I don't want the s3 path determined by the format of the input, for example, `year` is a string `000001999`, `month` is string `00004` and day is an integer `20`, I still want the path to be `xxx/1999/04/20`, is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Cecilia
So in the line below, `day` and `month` get converted to `str` if they are a `int` in the `:02d` fashion. However, if `day` or `month` is not `int`, just take the last two characters of the string.

`day, month = ['{0:02d}'.format(e if type(e) == int else int(e[-2:])) for e in [day, month]]` 

Same for year, assuming only years with 4 digits.

`year = str(year) if type(year) == int else year[-4:]`
    
Now you can return
`f'xxx/{year}/{month}/{day}'`

Answer (score 0):

You could cast to a datetime format, then cast to a string format:

```
from datetime import datetime

def construct_path(year, month, day):
    dt = datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
    dt_as_path = dt.strftime('xxx/%Y/%m/%d')
    return dt_as_path
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like the simplest way since it requires first creating a `datatime` object in order to be able to utilize its `strftime()` method.

Comment: A 2 liner using standard python modules is pretty simple in my opinion. Curious to see what other responses are provided @martineau

Comment: @Jelle Westra's answer is one line including the `return` and doesn't require importing any modules whatsoever — hard to imagine anything simpler than that…

Comment: Agreed. That is a very simple solution!